# External drive probleim with 14.04 compared to 12.04

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, drive

I had two Ubuntu machines until recently but unfortunately the motherboard in 12.04 machine had a terminal illness.  I now find that the 14.04 machine will have nothing to do with my 2TB backup drive or Nikon DSLR - it thinks thay are music/video disks.  There must be some driver missing, but I know not what.

Comment: What format is this drive?

Comment: The backup is ASDF and I am not sure about the Nikon but I would imagine     it will be the same.

Comment: having the same sort of problem here:

*https://askubuntu.com/questions/712629/shutting-down-disks-error*

Comment: I don't  know why I put ASDF, it should have been ntfs of course.